# How to Config eclipse CDT with Turbo C++ Compiler

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

How do I configure eclipse with Turbo C++ compiler.

Comment: Why? What's the point? Just to see if it's possible? Is the Turbo C++ compiler even separate from the IDE? I have no idea, I'm not old enough to have used it.

Comment: @CodyGray: there're separate executables, tcc.exe - just the compiler, tc.exe - IDE+compiler (or just IDE?). You can compile from the command line. Same with Turbo Pascal.

Comment: Interesting. It's good to know there's a solid base of compiler archaeologists here on SO if I ever need them.

Comment: @CodyGray: if you're old enough, you can know certain things that younger people don't. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: don't!

Embarcadero Technologies (which acquired all of Borland's compiler tools with the purchase of its CodeGear division in 2008) discontinued the support of Turbo C++ 2006. Why use a tool that was abandoned 6 years ago?

Turbo C++ was succeeded by C++Builder, which has it's own IDE.

If you want to do C++ development in Eclipse you should use [Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers (~107MB)](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

Answer (score 3):

Remember, Luke:

**Use following compilers to work with C++**:

- [MinGw](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/) on Windows / **gcc** on Linux
- Or even [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)
- Or [MSVC++](http://www.microsoft.com/express)

with the following IDEs:

- [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers-includes-incubating-components/indigosr1) (such a *monster*)
- Or [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) (not such a *moster*)
- Or **your favorite editor name here**

If everybody will use them it become peace in the world

**Do not use following**:

- Turbo c++
- Dev-c++
- Borland c++

Every time you use them, God kills a kitten!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with TurboC++ compiler, but you can create makefile and tell Eclipse to use it or provide path and parameters for Turbo C++ from your project settings -> C/C++ Build -> Builder Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Lol4t0, why **NOT** use the following:

"

> Do not use following:
>
> ```
> Turbo c++
> Dev-c++
> Borland c++
> ```
>
> "

Comment: Because they are outdated and pure supported. Since Turbo C++ stopped developing C++ was standardized (3 times), a lot of libraries and opportunities were added to the language.