# Turbo C++ using C language by default?

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I've recently gotten Turbo C++ 3.0 compiler from my school computer, for making both C and C++ programs, however it doesn't seem to recognize C++ code.

For example if I add `#include <iostream>` it's saying it can't find
`iostream` library and I can't use expressions such as `cout`. (I should
also mention I tried `#include "iostream"`)

This logically means it's giving me errors for any C++ related function.

I've also tried to import other specific C++ libraries such as `<string.h>` but it's not working.

Writing C code in Turbo C++ works like a charm, I've written several programs with no error whatsoever in them however the problems only come up when I try to code C++.

Is there a "Turn-on" for C++ in Turbo C++ 3.0? The compiler is rather confusing to be honest, and I've looked in the settings but found nothing particularly helpful.

Also I'm sorry if this isn't an appropriate question but I don't know where to ask it and I'm running pretty desperate.

Comment: About time to throw away turbo C++ and move to greener pastures of gcc and msvc.

Comment: Turbo C++ 3 was released in 1991. The first ISO C++ standard appeared in 1998. Do the math.

Comment: What is extension of your source file?

Comment: please always use `code mode` when using syntax of `include`, because `#` and `<...>` has special meaning on SO

Comment: @hmjd, extensions of ALL files written in TC++ are CPP

Comment: Try using #include <iostream.h> - with the .h suffix - or switch over a more modern compiler as the C++ standard has moved along a lot in the last 20 years! Nice to know schools are still teaching 20 year old 16-bit DOS programming! Good to install that heritage in programmers of today!

Comment: Whoa, there's clang, there's gcc and people still dig up those old C++ compiler attempts. An archeologist, perhaps? :)

Comment: Thanks Trevor Tippins. That helped.

Answer (score 2):

Turbo C++ 3.0 was released in 1991, long before the C++ language was standardized.  That didn't happen until 1998.  You'll have plenty of trouble writing standard compliant code.  I think it had an implementation of iostreams but the header file was named iostream.h.  Expect it to resemble the standard stream classes only in passing.

This is not worth your time.  Not when [compliant implementations](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express) are freely available.

Comment: Why most of people advise only MSVC express, while there are a lot of alternatives?

Comment: Why do people complain about it in comments when they can post an answer that mentions them?

Comment: @Lol4t0 - If you program for Windows only, MSVC is a complete package, comes with an automatic installer, and runs out of the box. If you have no other specific requirements, it just works.

Comment: I installed MinGw with NetBeans and I had to click `OK` sometimes only. I don't say, that MSVC is bad.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you do not set correct *include directory* for standard c++ labrary. This option should be turned with `Options -> Directories`, as I can remember

If you just copied compiler from your school computer, you may forget to copy standard library files.

C does not require such files, so, it works fine.

Also, please, consider using [modern compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8838581/774651)

Comment: No I copied an installer from school, and I do have my library directory