# How to suggest custom filenames via auto-completion in Notepad++

Tags: autocomplete, notepad++

I am using Notepad++ (on windows) to edit my C++ code (then compile it using g++).

When I type `#include<`, I would like a suggestion list to be displayed with all the available header files in the header files directory (or already added list of header files), just like it happens when I type function-names and the suggestions show up for autocompletion.

The "Style Configurator" has no such options under preprocessor directives.

Please tell me the way to achieve it (step-by-step if possible).

Comment: Just as a side note: Notepad++ might not be the best choice as being (mis-)used as an IDE (because it isn't really an IDE). I'd recommend to use Eclipse CDT, or some other more appropriate IDE.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks for the suggestion, I know. We are taught using Turbo C++ at school, so I am just trying to make myself comfortable with g++ since Turbo is ancient now.

Comment: And please provide a reason when downvoting (if possible).

Comment: _"We are taught using Turbo C++ at school,"_ That's even the worst combination of _IDE_ and toolchain I can imagine. Your teachers are torturing you with unreal stuff, you'll almost never meet in real life environments nowadays.

Comment: I know, it's sad. But we can't help it. I have to learn to adapt with newer compilers myself :(

Comment: See [How to Config eclipse CDT with Turbo C++ Compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838017/how-to-config-eclipse-cdt-with-turbo-c-compiler). There's no implication to use notepad++ with Turbo C++.

Comment: I am NOT using Turbo C++ with Notepad, I am using g++ with Notepad++, in order to escape from downloading an IDE.

Comment: _"We are taught using Turbo C++ at school"_ There are notable differences when using Turbo C++ and GCC. I've opened a [meta discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276401/how-to-deal-with-turbo-c-restricted-specific-questions) BTW.

Comment: That is why __I have to learn to adapt with newer compilers myself__

Comment: They've taught you the wrong stuff. The standard header file names are different and such. Just use e.g. Eclipse CDT along with latest GCC toolchain, to get a good grip.

Comment: _@Kunal Gupta_ And just FYI: I wasn't the downvoter.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I know that. Else, you would not be providing with me suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In other **SynWrite** editor: create simple Python plugin, which will act on Ctrl+Space press: it must suggest filenames from any dir.

Notepad++ cannot do it.

Comment: Not necessarily directories, even a predefined list could do if that's possible in NP++.